# How can I average the last n number of rows when using a Average(Index, match formula)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets one has a table with sets across the top of the table and daily km for each set the second sheet has set numbers in column b,  I wish to find the daily average for the last 6 months (so 182 days) for each of the sets and return the value in column F.

Sheet 2

[image]

sheet 1 - Table

[image]

I have used the following formula to average the entire column
`=AVERAGE(INDEX(Table1[[H9003]:[H9043]],0,MATCH('FA Forecasts'!B5,Table1[[#Headers],[H9003]:[H9043]],0)))`

However I only want to return the average of the last 182 rows of the table to the corresponding set number - and each time a new line is added I only want the last 182 rows.

I'm not sure what I can do to achieve this - any advice would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```
=LET(indexSetNumber,MATCH([@[Set Number]],tblSheet1[#Headers],0),
filterByDate,FILTER(tblSheet1,tblSheet1[Date]>=LARGE(tblSheet1[Date],cntDays)),
filterBySet,INDEX(filterByDate,,indexSetNumber),
AVERAGE(filterBySet))
```

I like "readable" formulas - this one reads like this:

- `indexSetNumber`: returns the column index of e.g. H9003 --> 5
- `filterByDate`: returns the rows with Top "cntDays" dates. I am using a `parameter` cntDays in `C2` - for this example I chose 2, but you would put 182.
- `filterBySet`: returns column `indexSetNumber` from `filterByDate`
- from these values `AVERAGE` is returned.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - the logic looks great.  However currently my excel does not appear to be the latest version! I'll be onto our IT dept. to have this fixed so I can explore this further.

Answer (score 1):

This might also work (assuming C2 is `=TODAY()`):

`=AVERAGEIF(Table1[Date],">" & C2 - F2,INDIRECT("Table1["& 'FA Forecasts'!B5 &"]"))`

Using [AVERAGEIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642) formula :

- `Table1[Date]` : returns the "Date" table column (sheet 1)
- `">" & C2 - F2` : "date more recent than Today-182 days"
- `INDIRECT("Table1["& 'FA Forecasts'!B5 &"]")` : returns the table column (sheet 1) which header match with `Set Number` in the current row (sheet 2)

Basically return the average for kms in the past 182 days for the Set Number of the row.